# Using databox disk for uploading data to fileshare

Tags: azure-storage, azure-files

I have ordered azure data box disk to copy data form my local device to azure fileshare.

What I want to understand is, whether data box will create a new fileshare or can I have the option to upload it to already created fileshare?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this really isn't a question for Stack Overflow. Maybe ServerFault? Not sure it's on-topic there either, as this might be considered a documentation question.

Comment: ok let me try there, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Box will not create a new File Share. You need to manually create a File Share.

You can use the existing File share instead of creating a new one

Please refer this link to use Data Box to migrate Data to Azure file shares :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-migration-nas-cloud-databox#migration-overview

Comment: Just wanted to know can we copy data to already created/existing fileshare or there is no option, we have to create one?

Comment: You can use the existing fileshare instead of creating a new one. I have edited the answer

Comment: I don't see the how-to in the document. Do you have any references?

Comment: Please refer Phase 2 and Phase 5 of the above mentioned document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-migration-nas-cloud-databox#migration-overview